# Empty (but working) show method on controller generated via scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How is that the `show` method on a controller class generated via `rails generate scaffold xxx` empty / contains no code? Where is the code for showing individual records via URL e.g. `/my_rails_app:3000/xxx/1` stored?

The method should, at the very least, looks like this IMO:

```
class ProductController
  # GET /students/1
  # GET /students/1.json
  def show
    @item = Product.find(params[:id])
    render @item
  end
end
```

but instead it is completely empty:

```
class ProductController
  # GET /students/1
  # GET /students/1.json
  def show

  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have anything in `before_filter`? BTW, line `render @item` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using rails 4 then there should have some before action method which is doing the magic for you please check in the respective controller.

It should be like `before_action :set_product, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`